# Auto _ptr implementation

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

```
double **mat;
int i,j;
mat=new double *[a];
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    mat[i]=new double [b];
}
return(mat);
```

I wrote this code to allocate memory. I am facing bad memory allocation error. This particular function is called more than 10000 times in my code. I want to use auto_ptr while allocating memory. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Auto_ptr doesn't do arrays.

[std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will <s>with a custom deleter</s> with the typical `new[]`/`delete[]` usecase, but there's a much simpler way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> mat(a,std::vector<double>(b))
```

Slightly more complicated, but much faster due to [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) is to use a 1 dimensional vector.

```
std::vector<double> mat(a*b)
```

and manually do the dimensioning with

```
mat[row*b+column]
```

Comment: You don't need a custom deleter just to use `std::unique_ptr` with an array. You only need a custom deleter if the array was not allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Seems I misinterpreted something I once read (or read something that was wrong). Should have taken a better look at the link I posted. Thanks for clearing that up @RemyLebeau .

Comment: The above answer seems working but return command is making error

Comment: @SakthiVel What is the error message? Did you change the return type of the function to match the new type of the data's container?

Comment: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<std::vector<double> >' to 'double**' in return

Comment: I dont know how to change the return type

Comment: @SakthiVel In the function prototype you need to change `double**` to `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`. Where you call this function, you need to change the receiving variable type to `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` as well. Usage is about the same.